# Como habilitar y deshabitar un input de text en Angular 8?

Tags: validación

Angular 8, como habilito y deshabito un input de tipo text y que me funcione la validacion. No me fuciona
los pasos que describo, podrian ayudar en que me estoy equivocando?.

Tengo en mi archivo html lo siguiente:

Telefono requerido

```
 <br />

<button type="button" (click)="habilitar()">habilitar</button>
<button type="button" (click)="desabilitar()">desabilitar</button>
```

En mi archivo ts tengo lo siguiente:

```
myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        "telefono": [""]
});

habilitar()
{
    this.myForm.get("telefono").enable();

    let controlTelefono = this.myForm.get("telefono");
    controlTelefono.setValidators([Validators.required]);
}

desabilitar()
{
    this.myForm.get("telefono").disable();

    let controlTelefono = this.myForm.get("telefono");
    controlTelefono.etValidators(null);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Espero que te ayude, no entendi mucho lo que querias dejar dicho.

Este es el html:

```
<input type="text" id="input" [readonly]="readonly"/>
<button type="button" (click)="habilitar()">habilitar</button>
<button type="button" (click)="desabilitar()">desabilitar</button>
```

Este tu archivo .ts:

```
  readonly = null;
habilitar(){
  //mostrar
  document.getElementById("input").style.visibility = "visible";
  //habilitar
  this.readonly = false;
}

desabilitar(){
  //ocultar
  document.getElementById("input").style.visibility = "collapse";
  //deshabilitar
  this.readonly= true;
}
```